# Pandas: Counting matching values in each row of a giant dataframe, based on info from smaller dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have one large df formatted like this:

```
df1 = 
ID    char
r1    foo
r2    foo
r5    bar
r9    bar
...   ...
```

And another even larger one formatted like this:

```
df2 = 
ID    a12   b23    c81   ...
r1    foo   baz    bar   ...
r2    foo   foo    bar   ...
r3    bar   bar    baz   ...
r4    bar   baz    bar   ...
...   ...   ...    ...
```

Looking at the ID row in both df, I want to collect the count of how many of the rest of the colums match. So for ID `r1`, I look at that row in df2 and see only `a12` matches. I want to keep track of every match, so for the first row I'd have

```
a12    1
b23    0
c81    0
```

Some rows in df2 do not have a row in df1 (df2 has an `r4` row and df1 does not). The totals for this example would be:

```
a12    2
b23    1
c81    0
```

df1 is a .csv that can be loaded into memory, but df2 is so large that I load it in chunks. So to compare the two, I would load them both in, then have to start with something like:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\me\\df1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_table("C:\\Users\\me\\df2.vcf.gz", header = None, names = header_line, engine = 'c',
                       compression = 'gzip', chunksize = 40000, low_memory=False)

for chunk in df2:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge the `DataFrames` together and then use `.eq` to see which columns equal the `'char'` column.

```
s = pd.Series()
for chunk in df2:
    merged = df1.merge(chunk, on='ID')
    s = s.add(merged[[col for col in chunk.columns if col != 'ID']].eq(merged.char, axis=0).sum(), 
              fill_value=0)
```

#### Output: `s`

```
a12    2.0
b23    1.0
c81    0.0
dtype: float64
```